# Error cannot read property 'users' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm getting an error that I'm unable to figure out why it's happening. I'm trying to get the guild owner `message.guild.owner.user.tag` but it's giving me a type error `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`.

Heres what I'm working with:

```
module.exports = new Command({
name: "server",
description: "Shows server info",
permission: "SEND_MESSAGES",
async run(message, args, client) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    const created = moment(message.guild.createdAt).format('LL');
    
    {
        embed
        .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}`)
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .addFields(
            {
                name: "Total Members",
                value: `${message.guild.memberCount}`,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: "Created on",
                value: `${created}`,
                inline: true
            },
            {
                name: "Owner",
                value: message.guild.owner.user.tag, // issue on this line
                inline: false

            },
            {
                name: "Verification Level",
                value: `${message.guild.verificationLevel}`,
                inline: false

            } 
        ); 

    message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
}
    
}


        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Guild` only provides an `.ownerId` property, to retrieve the `User` object of the owner you must fetch by the id.

```js
const { guild } = message;
const { ownerId } = guild;
const owner = (await guild.members.fetch(ownerId)).user;

// owner.tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Guild hasn't the property 'owner', you can only get the owner's user id like so:

```js
message.guild.ownerId
```